# Number of connected components of the isometry group of a simply-connected lorentzian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lorentzian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a finite-dimensional connected lorentzian manifold.  Then the group $G$ of isometries of $M$ (i.e., the group of diffeomorphisms $\varphi : M \to M$ with $\varphi^* g = g$) is a Lie group.  (See, e.g., the answer to this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141417/isometry-group-of-pseudo-riemannian-manifold-always-a-lie-group-myers-steenrod).)

It is not difficult to construct examples of $(M,g)$ whose $G$ has infinitely many connected components, but they all share the property that the fundamental group is infinite.  (See, e.g., this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0814).)

**Question:** Suppose that $M$ is simply connected.  Can $G$ still have infinitely many connected components?  If so, then what about if $M$ is not just simply connected but also homogeneous?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Even when $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, the isometry group can have infinitely many components.  For example, the generic Lorentzian metric that is invariant under the lattice of translations $\mathbb{Z}^2\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ will have $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as its isometry group, and this has infinitely many components.

As for the homogeneous case, that's another matter, I guess.  I'll have to think about this and get back to you, but I expect that, in that case, it has only a finite number of components.

Comment: Thanks, Robert.  I was indeed to hasty in writing the question.  I see how a generic lorentzian metric on the 2-torus pulls back to a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a discrete group of isometries.  The case I'm really interested in is that of a homogeneous lorentzian manifold, so I look forward to any comments you can make in that situation.  Cheers!